# Como filtrar um SELECT com n:m e trazer todas caracteristicas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou utilizando `n:m` para criar um sistema de atributos/características para determinados produtos, assim eu posso reaproveitar os mesmos atributos para mais de um produto, a tabela é algo como:

[image: estrutura mysql n:m]

Quando executo um SELECT assim:

```
SELECT
    PROD.id         AS PRODUTO_ID,
    PROD.name       AS PRODUTO_NOME,
    PROD.price      AS PRODUTO_PRECO,
    ATTR.id         AS ATRIBUTO_ID,
    ATTR.attribute  AS ATRIBUTO_NOME
FROM
    products PROD,
    attributes ATTR,
    products_has_attributes PHA
WHERE
    PROD.id = PHA.products_id AND ATTR.id = PHA.attributes_id
```

Ele me retorna isto:

```
PRODUTO_ID | PRODUTO_NOME | PRODUTO_PRECO | ATRIBUTO_ID  | ATRIBUTO_NOME
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1         |  hb20        |  29000.00     |  1           |  ar condicionado
 1         |  hb20        |  29000.00     |  2           |  teto solar
 2         |  onix        |  350000.00    |  2           |  teto solar
 3         |  hilux       |  80000.00     |  1           |  ar condicionado
 3         |  hilux       |  80000.00     |  3           |  banco couro
 3         |  hilux       |  80000.00     |  4           |  novo
```

Eu quero consultar por exemplo todos carros/produtos que tem ar condicionado, então o `WHERE` seria algo como:

```
WHERE
    PROD.id = PHA.products_id AND ATTR.id = PHA.attributes_id
    AND
    ATTR.attribute = 'teto solar'
```

Ele retorna isto:

```
PRODUTO_ID | PRODUTO_NOME | PRODUTO_PRECO | ATRIBUTO_ID  | ATRIBUTO_NOME
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1         |  hb20        |  29000.00     |  2           |  teto solar
 2         |  onix        |  350000.00    |  2           |  teto solar
```

Então a minha consulta encontrou apenas os carros que tem teto solar, mas eu gostaria de obter todos atributos dos carros/produtos encontrados ao mesmo tempo que faço a consulta/filtragem, ou seja eu gostaria que retorna-se algo como:

```
PRODUTO_ID | PRODUTO_NOME | PRODUTO_PRECO | ATRIBUTO_ID  | ATRIBUTO_NOME
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1         |  hb20        |  29000.00     |  1           |  ar condicionado
 1         |  hb20        |  29000.00     |  2           |  teto solar
 2         |  onix        |  350000.00    |  2           |  teto solar
```

Se eu usar `SELECT` para buscar "ar condicionado" e "novo":

```
WHERE
    PROD.id = PHA.products_id AND ATTR.id = PHA.attributes_id
    AND
    ATTR.attribute = 'sunroof' AND ATTR.attribute = 'new'
```

Eu preciso que retorne algo como:

```
PRODUCT_ID | PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_PRICE | ATTR_ID      | ATTR_NAME
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3         |  hilux       |  80000.00     |  1           |  ar condicionado
 3         |  hilux       |  80000.00     |  3           |  banco couro
 3         |  hilux       |  80000.00     |  4           |  novo
```

Estrutura usada no exemplo:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`products` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL (10,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`attributes` (
  `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attribute` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`products_has_attributes` (
  `products_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `attributes_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`, `attributes_id`),
  INDEX `fk_products_has_attributes_attributes1_idx` (`attributes_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_products_has_attributes_products_idx` (`products_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_products_has_attributes_products`
    FOREIGN KEY (`products_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`products` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_products_has_attributes_attributes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`attributes_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`attributes` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

INSERT INTO `attributes` (`id`, `attribute`) VALUES
(1, 'ar condicionado'),
(2, 'teto solar'),
(4, 'banco couro'),
(5, 'novo');

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 'hb20', '29000.00'),
(2, 'onix', '350000.00'),
(3, 'hilux', '80000.00');

INSERT INTO `products_has_attributes` (`products_id`, `attributes_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(3, 1),
(1, 2),
(3, 2),
(3, 4),
(3, 5);
```

Comment: Use uma subquery   http://imasters.com.br/artigo/253/sql-server/trabalhando-com-subquerys/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça o select sobre a tabela de ligação entre produtos e atributos de modo a repetir um produto tantas vezes quantas atributos diferentes ele tiver.

O filtro que decide de qual produto serão trazidos os atributos está na subquery, que por sua vez é filtrada pela query principal.

```
SELECT
    products.id         AS PRODUTO_ID,
    products.name       AS PRODUTO_NOME,
    products.price      AS PRODUTO_PRECO,
    attributes.id         AS ATRIBUTO_ID,
    attributes.attribute  AS ATRIBUTO_NOME
FROM
    products_has_attributes PHA
    JOIN attributes ON attributes.id = PHA.attributes_id
    JOIN products ON products.id = PHA.products_id
WHERE
    EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 
                products_has_attributes.products_id
            FROM
                products_has_attributes 
                JOIN attributes ON attributes.id = products_has_attributes.attributes_id
            WHERE 
                products_has_attributes.products_id = PHA.products_id
                AND attributes.attribute = 'teto solar'
        )
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f684b/3/0).

**Edição:** A query abaixo atende também seu novo requisito, que é: dado dois atributos como parâmetro, retornar todos os atributos de cada produto que possua no mínimo estes dois parâmetros.

```
SELECT
    products.id         AS PRODUTO_ID,
    products.name       AS PRODUTO_NOME,
    products.price      AS PRODUTO_PRECO,
    attributes.id         AS ATRIBUTO_ID,
    attributes.attribute  AS ATRIBUTO_NOME
FROM
    products_has_attributes PHA
    JOIN attributes ON attributes.id = PHA.attributes_id
    JOIN products ON products.id = PHA.products_id
WHERE
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            products_has_attributes 
            JOIN attributes ON attributes.id = products_has_attributes.attributes_id
        WHERE 
            products_has_attributes.products_id = PHA.products_id
            AND 
                (
                    attributes.attribute = 'teto solar'
                    OR attributes.attribute = 'ar condicionado'
                )
    ) = 2
```

Nesta nova query, cada novo parâmetro é conectado por **OR** na subquery e o **COUNT** da subquery tem que retornar tantos registros quantos parâmetros houver. Observe que a lógica funciona para qualquer quantidade de parâmetros - basta adicionar um *or* e a ajustar a comparação (*"= X"* onde X é o número de parâmetros).

Comment: Ótima resposta, só tenho uma duvida, é fora do escopo, porém se você puder me responder. Esta maneira que criei para adicionar atributos aos produtos é a mais "correta/recomendada"?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não vejo nada errado com a sua modelagem. Eu faria assim também se produto é realmente algo tão específico (no exemplo, automóveis). Eu apenas não usaria o *has_* no nome de tabela; chamaria de *products_attributes*.

Comment: É que sou preguiçoso e por isto uso o WorkBench :) Obrigado!

Comment: eu não sei se abro outra questão, mas é assim se eu precisar pesquisar os carros com duas características especificas ele não retorna nada `AND attributes.attribute = 'teto solar' AND attributes.attribute = 'ar condicionado'` e se eu usar `OR` ao invés de `AND` `and (attributes.attribute = 'teto solar' or attributes.attribute = 'ar condicionado')` se o carro já tiver `teto solar` irá ser listado, mesmo que não tenha `ar condicionado`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Acho que não chega a ser um novo problema mas apenas um requisito que você esqueceu de mencionar antes. Atualizei a resposta com a solução para isso.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado mais uma vez

Comment: Só voltei hoje aqui, pois queria ressaltar que o uso de `EXISTS` ou `ANY` como você sugeriu é realmente o melhor caminho, pois assim evitará problemas com paginação por exemplo. Mais uma vez obrigado.